# Unable to call procedure with arguments in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

No matter what I've tried, I get the PLS-00103 error with the mesage:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
DECLARE
  MyVar NUMBER(12,0);
BEGIN
  HISTORY.sp_CHS_Insert('OMSC01', 522‚ 'OMSC01' ,522 , 4, 'S14_DCSKOLIZE', 'CHYBA', MyVar);
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: řádka 4, sloupec 38:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & = - + < / > at v is mod remainder not rem =>
   <exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
 Symbol ", was inserted before"‚", so continuation would be possible.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

My procedure's header is below. The procedure is in package HISTORY:

```
procedure sp_CHS_Insert(
  ParH01Source in OMSH01.H01Source%type,
  ParH01ExtID in OMSH01.H01ExtId%type,
  ParH01UpdSource in OMSH01.H01UpdSource%type,
  ParH01UpdExtId in OMSH01.H01UpdExtId%type,

  ParXUR01UserID in XUR01.XUR01UserID%type := null,
  ParS14Code in OMSS14.S14Code%type := null,
  ParS12Code in OMSS12.S12Code%type := null,
  ParH01ID out OMSH01.H01ID%type
);
```

And the calling SQL looks like this:

```
DECLARE
  MyVar NUMBER(12,0);
BEGIN
  HISTORY.sp_CHS_Insert('OMSC01', 555‚ 'OMSC01' ,555, 4, 'S14_DCSKOLIZE', 'CHYBA', MyVar);
END;
```

I've checked the parameter types and they are correct. I am running the scripts via SQL Developer.

I am a PLSQL newbie (a .NET dev forced to do PLSQL) and I know it is probably something really obvious, but I just can't see it.

Comment: This looks like an error with the call rather than the PL/SQL. Are you calling it from .NET and what does this call look like

Comment: Nope, I'm not calling it from from .NET. I just run the script (the one calling the procedure) directly from SQL Developer

Comment: Can you post the full error from SQL Developer then. You're missing the codes and I wouldn't expect `"line %s, column %s:\n%s"` to appear...

Comment: and I've just realised the problem... your Procedure would not have compiled. Assigning default values in the declaration should be done like `ParS12Code in OMSS12.S12Code%type default null` not using `:=`

Comment: I think the procedure should be fine, because it preceeds this problem and it has been running without a problem in a production environment for a couple of years. (Btw. the procedure itself is not my code)

Comment: I've also added the full error from SQL Developer as per your request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "comma" in position 38 (following the first `522`) is not an ASCII comma.  When I copied your code into SQL Developer, it looked slightly different, and when I checked the ASCII function returns 130 when passed this character, whereas a normal comma would return 44.

Comment: It certainly looks identical on this website! "Encountered , but expected , instead"? Oh.